# Gimp export project as an image to PDF, I want my texts to stay as text

Tags: gimp, pdf, export

I designed CV in GIMP.
Today I had a call with my future employer.
And she said that my CV is great but not useful because she can't select any text from my CV to copy it.

Maybe is there some way to export Gimp project as a PDF where I can normally select text ?

Ofc I have text as a text in gimp :

[image]

Best regards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GIMP's export as PDF rasterizes texts if the text layers are placed into a layer group folder. Export option "vectorize when possible" doesn't change that. If texts are as normal non-grouped layers, texts stay as text in the PDF.

Comment: Thats the reason. But is there a way to group elements with text and keep it well in pdf?

Comment: @PatrykJanik I haven't found such way - except lifting manually one by one the texts out of their layer groups  before exporting. A programmer might crush together an extension script for that. I believe your best bet is to leave GIMP for images and take some better fitting program for your documents. If you want to use freeware, check the Open Office collection and Scribus. As a first aid offer to send the texts separately.

Comment: Yeah, but that's weird. Shouldn't it be a bug as there is different behaviour when text is in group and when not?

Answer (score -1):

Hola tambien tenia el mismo problema que a la hora de exportar el documento gimp a pdf me movia el texto. Deja las cosas como vienen por default a la hora de exportar o quita solamente "omitir las capas ocultas y las que tienen opacidad cero" (Siempre y cuando no tengas capas ocultas en el diseño).

Y finalmente el texto que se mueva o no se queda en su lugar en el diseño al exportarlo, conviertelo a capa ya sea con la "herramienta de transformación unificada" u otra opción y queda estatico.

Hello, I also had the same problem that when exporting the gimp document to pdf, the text moved. Leave things as default when exporting or just remove "skip hidden layers and those with zero opacity" (As long as you don't have hidden layers in the design).

And finally the text that moves or does not stay in place in the design when exported, convert it to a layer either with the "unified transform tool" or another option and it remains static.